# checkbox that is not positive or negative

Tags: buttons, checkboxes

I am looking for a multiple choice checkbox that is not positive or negative just a mark.
where have you seen examples for such buttons?

I am building a process that allows to approve or reject videos from a list of videos.
and I want the user to have the ability to choose multiple videos and approve or reject them at once.

[image: not mark]

[image: mark]

Comment: You can simply use two radio boxes which are unselected by default.

Comment: Could you provide a mock-up showing what you're thinking about?

Comment: It's very similar to email inbox. User multi-select emails and do an action. You can use gray or any other natural color to imply that.

Comment: You think I should use the check mark but leave it grey?http://imgur.com/DDxxMJV

Comment: isn't a checkbox inherently neutral already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the main goal of the screen is either to approve (publish), or reject videos, it's better to use more prominent controls, like primary buttons.

The scenario for multiple approving/rejecting is:

1. User selects several videos
2. User clicks either Publish, or Reject button

[image]

The advantages:
• The actions are prominent (primary actions are obvious)
• The actions are close to selection (increased efficiency of use)
• Use Publish as a label. It shows the final result, otherwise it looks like user need both to Approve, and Publish. The better name for the header is Publish Videos, for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

You have a binary process **(yes/no, on/off, approve/delete)** so you should use an element that allows for this behavior, such as [radio](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/radio) or [**toggle switch**](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/switch.html) . In your particular case, where you don't want 2 elements, but just one, I'd go with the **switch**.

An undetermined status would be very confusing unless you clearly label this and explain the user what to expect. One example of your behavior is Filezilla's **Change File Attribute** screen:

[image]

Here, you can have 3 states: **unchecked, checked and "neutral"** to keep the original permissions. But this is a really confusing way to do things and I'm providing it just as **an example on how NOT to do it**

Also, take a look to [Checkbox vs toggle](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63884/checkbox-vs-toggle)  at UXSE for some additional information and concerns