toggle vs checkbox
I’m unsure about when to use a toggle versus a checkbox. As I understand it, toggles are typically used when changes take effect immediately, without the need for a confirmation button.
However, I’ve noticed toggles being used in modals that include a required confirmation button at the bottom. I don’t necessarily see an issue with this, but I don’t fully understand the thought process behind using toggles in such cases instead of checkboxes.
Could someone clarify when it’s appropriate to use a toggle in this kind of context?

Note that there are many similar questions about this topic. Did you search for it? For example: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63884/checkbox-vs-toggle

You are right! :) Toggles are used to indicate an immediate, often binary state change, while checkboxes are for selecting options that may require confirmation. In modals, toggles show the state, and the confirmation button ensures the user confirms their intention to apply the change.
